# Prove that "open first quadrant" in $l^1$ i.e $R=\{x=(x_k)_{n\in{N}}\in{l^1}:\;\;x_k>0\;\text{for every }x_k\}$, is not open

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I have some problem to working with open balls and open sets.

The problem is stated as follow

Let $R$ be the "open first quadrant" in $l^1$ i.e
$R=\{x=(x_k)_{n\in{N}}\in{l^1}:\;\;x_k>0\;\text{for every }x_k\}$,

Show that the set is not open.

Any hints how to start the proof?

Is it correct that an open ball $l^1$ is given by
$x=(x_n),y=(y_n)\in{l^1}$ is given by
$B_r(x)=\{y_n\in{l^1}:\sum^\infty_{n=1}|x_n-y_n|<r<\infty\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your definition of the open ball is fine. But I would look at it from another angle. Rather prove the equivalent statement that
$$
\ell^1 \setminus R = \lbrace x_n \in \ell^1: \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }x_n \leq 0 \rbrace
$$
is not closed. For this let $x_n \in R$ be given by $x_n := \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $(x^{(j)})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \ell^1 \setminus R$ be the sequence of sequences defined by
$$
x_n^{(j)} :=
\begin{cases}
 0,~n=j \\
 \frac{1}{n^2},~ \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Then:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert x_n^{(j)} - x_n \rvert = \frac{1}{j^2} \overset{j \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
Thus the sequence $x^{(j)}$ has a limit that lies outside of $\ell^1\setminus R$, meaning that $\ell^1 \setminus R$ is not closed.

(This is also a proof for the fact that there is no open ball centered at $x_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ that lies completely in $R$)

Comment: What does the sequence $x^{j}_{n}$ means i do not remember?

Comment: For every FIXED $j \in \mathbb{N}$, $(x_n^{(j)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an element of $\ell^1 \setminus R$. We proved that $x_n^j$ converges to $x_n$ in the $\ell^1$ metric.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct $x^j_n$ converges componentwise to $x_n$

Comment: This is a consequence of what i proved, and not quite the statement that I made. I said that $x_n^j$ converges in the $\ell^1$-metric (do you know what I mean by that) to $x_n$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand the last step, I am pretty new to proofs. I will be very happy if you have time explain

Comment: You should educate yourself about metric spaces first. We are dealing with the metric space $\ell^1$ and the metric $d(x, y) := \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert x_n - y_n \rvert$. A subset $A$ of $\ell^1$ is closed iff every sequence in $A$ that converges in $\ell^1$ has its limit in $A$, too. We found a sequence in $\ell^1 \setminus R$ which converges but its limit is not in $\ell^1 \setminus R$, meaning that the latter is not closed, meaning that $R$ is not open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127995/discussion-between-tor-erik-haavik-and-meowdog).